# Post database from local sql server to azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have webapi2 project and database on local MS SQL Server.

I need to publish project with database

With publishing project all okay it published and works.

But tables not published.

I set database connection in Web.config file like this

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB"
    connectionString="Server=tcp:trackingappserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=trackingappdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Id and password is correct.

How I can post database?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-migrate-import-export
Check official docs.

Comment: I have MS SQL Server , not MySQL database@BobSwager

Comment: Found docs for sql server@BobSwager

Comment: I edited your topics. Did you solve your issue?